# TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send' Django

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, django-channels, asgi

***When I run the project through the gunicorn (command: gunicorn --bind :8000 myproject.asgi:application), I get this error.***

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.base')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from chats import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    ),
})
```

**chats.routing.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/messages/(?P<username>[-:\w]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Comment: Give more details: Django version, are you using some cloud service?.. Please review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am getting same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I have filed an issue on channels official github site: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1735

Comment: for me, I'm working on pytest and using `WebsocketCommunicator` and I missing to add `.as_asgi()` on it, `WebsocketCommunicator(AnnouncementConsumer.as_asgi(), f"/announcement/?token={auth_token.key}")`

Answer (score 20):

[There is an issue on github similar to your problem](https://github.com/django/channels/discussions/1736)

Answer:  Likely you missed the `as_asgi()` in your `routing.py`

Comment: but you are using `consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()`, so maybe the syntax is wrong, or you could file another issue there?

Comment: I have already solved mine by adding `.as_asgi()` after my path. Don't know what makes your problem unsolved.